# Cant boot back into windows10 cant install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

**HELP Cant boot back into windows10 cant install Ubuntu**
I decided I wanted to try to dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, so I followed [This Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvBZBfY5Pfc), everything was going smoothly until I got this:

> *Force UEFI Installation? This machines's firmware has started this installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there maybe existing operating systems already installed using BIOS compatibility mode, If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode,it might be difficult to reboot into any BIOS-mode operating system.*

I decided to force the installation. Continuing on, everything seemed okay, I went through the wizard and the installation began smoothly. Until, near the end of the installation I get an error that pops up saying

> "*The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot load, the installed system will not boot.*"

I click "okay" and send the error report as that is the only option. Now I am stuck in "trying Ubuntu without installing". When I boot, the grub menu only has the "Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu", and some system setting options.

So I can't get back into windows, and I can't install Ubuntu. I would really just like to get back to windows. Any advice would be amazing. Thanks.

PS. I have tried boot repair, and it did not seem to work. Here is the boot repair [pastebin](http://%22The%20'grub-efi-amd64-signed'%20package%20failed%20to%20install%20into%20/target/.%20Without%20the%20GRUB%20boot%20load,%20the%20installed%20system%20will%20not%20boot.%22).

Comment: What are you using to do the installation ? and are you booting from the installation media?

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/

Comment: Continue from the install ubuntu, then choose install alongside windows.

Comment: I am installing from a usb like the tutorial linked above that I followed. I do choose install alongside windows, and then when installing get the above error:  "The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot load, the installed system will not boot."

Comment: Your Boot Repair link is no good. Please try again, but be sure to post a valid URL. That will be helpful in offering an answer that's better than an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to ensure that the data on the hard disk is secure. So, boot into a live session of Ubuntu through "Try Ubuntu without installing" and check out the drives.

Next, try re-installing Ubuntu the right way [as explained here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside_8.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to boot to Windows after editing the UEFI settings.
Enter to the UEFI Settings menu by selecting that System Settings option from the `grub` menu, then try to find a setting related to the boot drive, and change that to the partition Windows is installed on. I cannot make a step by step tutorial because firmwares differ from a machine to another so the UEFI Settings menu does.

This will only work if the Windows partition was kept untouched during the installation of Ubuntu, and all of the data on it -most importantly system files- are healthy.